# 2 scripts cancelling each other out

Tags: jquery

SOLVED: removing all reference to noconflict fixed the issue

I have 2 scripts (PART A and PART B) which work perfectly on there own to do 2 separate tasks. when i put them both on the one page, one cancels the other out. any help appreciated.

```
// PART A
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($j) {

var image_slides = [];

image_slides.push({
image: 'img/background.jpg'
})

$j.supersized({

min_width: 0,
min_height: 0,
vertical_center: 1,
horizontal_center: 1,
fit_always: 0,
fit_portrait: 1,
fit_landscape: 0,
slides: image_slides,
});
}); 

// PART B
function cent() {
var $block = $("#block"),
    margintop = parseInt($block.height() / -2);
console.log('called');
$('#block').css("margin-top", margintop);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
cent();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
cent();
});
```

Comment: It's because you're calling `noConflict`, which is removing `$` as an alias to `jQuery`.

Comment: in this case, deleting PART A wil allow part B to work: http://jsfiddle.net/njs2p/19/

Comment: `jQuery(function ($j) {` makes no sense in this context. You already redefined your jQuery object as `$j`, thus you can just do `$j(function(){`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Part B in another function call to replace the `$` variable:

```
(function($) {
    // Part B
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery.noConflict()-call returns the global variable $ assignment to its original definition before jQuery was initialized. For instance you might have another library / method / property loaded on your page that stores a reference to itself inside $. Therefore all jQuery-specific methods used in part B, need to be invoked on variable $j instead of $.

As Joe Frambach answered : you can wrap part B code inside a method that passes the jQuery Object into an argument defined as "$". Here's why:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); // return reference of $ to original assignment

// calls to $ here are made in the global namespace, and not invoked on jQuery
// due to the noConflict-invocation above

(function( $ ) {

     // all calls to $ inside this function body are now invoked on jQuery as
     // jQuery is passed as an argument and we're now referencing a local namespace

})( jQuery );

// outside of the above function body calls to $ are made on the global namespace
// and thus not invoked on jQuery due to noConflict-invocation
```

Beware of integrating (external) scripts that were written for a jQuery-specific context when using "noConflict", as implementation is likely to need some work.